# Check if means break certain limits R

Tags: r

I have a 100x2 dataset, where the first column identifies the sample, and the second column represents the measurement. Each sample is of size 4, so the dataset looks like:

```
V1  V2
1   125.8
1   128.4
1   129.0
1   121.0
2   125.2
2   127.0
2   130.4
2   124.6
3   121.8
3   126.8
..  ..
```

I have calculated the mean for each sample using:

```
df2 = subset(data, select = c(2))
means =  t(sapply(split(df2,rep(seq(1,nrow(df2),4),each=4)),colMeans))
```

So I now have a vector of 25 means. I want to check if each of these means falls outside certain limits (defined below), and then return an object containing the sample ID, the mean value for the sample, and information on which limit it broke, setting the output to be of class "shewart":

```
warning_upper: 130.4
action_upper: 132.1
warning_lower: 123.6
action_lower: 121.9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was working on a solution at the same time when AntoniosK posted his.

I've also used the `dplyr` package:

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- read.table(text = "V1  V2
1   125.8
1   128.4
1   129.0
1   121.0
2   125.2
2   127.0
2   130.4
2   124.6
3   121.8
3   126.8
3   133.8
3   144.5", header = TRUE)

warn_upper <- 130.4
action_upper  <- 132.1
warn_lower <- 123.6
action_lower  <- 121.9

df1 %>%
        group_by(V1) %>%
        summarize(smean = mean(V2)) %>%
        mutate(warn_hi   = (smean - warn_upper) > 0 ,
               action_hi = (smean - action_upper ) > 0,
               warn_lo   = (-1 * (smean - warn_lower)) > 0 ,
               action_lo = (-1 * (smean - action_lower )) > 0) %>%
        mutate(klass = if_else(warn_lo | action_lo | 
                               warn_hi | action_hi, true = "shewart", false="" ))
```

Result:

```
     V1 smean warn_hi action_hi warn_lo action_lo  klass
  <int> <dbl>   <lgl>     <lgl>   <lgl>     <lgl>   <chr>
1     1 126.0   FALSE     FALSE   FALSE     FALSE        
2     2 126.8   FALSE     FALSE   FALSE     FALSE        
3     3 131.7    TRUE     FALSE   FALSE     FALSE shewart
```

Comment: This is great - thank you. Is "klass" specific to dplyr for defining a class? I haven't seen that before.

Comment: It's not that important, You could call that column name "class", probably. I have just tried to avoid  a name conflict with a built-in function name. Try class(df1)  perhaps to see what I mean. Same for colname smean .

Answer (score 1):

I've slightly changed the values you provided to make sure the process can spot correctly the pattern you want.

```
library(dplyr)

# example dataset
df = read.table(text = "
V1  V2
1   195.8
1   128.4
1   129.0
1   121.0
2   125.2
2   127.0
2   125.4
2   114.6
", header=T)

# function to return info based on a value
f = function(x) {
  ifelse(x < 121.9, "below action",
         ifelse(x < 123.6, "below warning", 
                ifelse(x > 132.1, "above action",
                       ifelse(x > 130.4, "above warning", "normal"))))
  }


df %>%
  group_by(V1) %>%                      # for each V1
  summarise(MeanValue = mean(V2)) %>%   # calculate means
  mutate(info = f(MeanValue))           # use the function to get relevant info

# # A tibble: 2 x 3
#      V1 MeanValue          info
#   <int>     <dbl>         <chr>
# 1     1    143.55  above action
# 2     2    123.05 below warning
```